# Configuring Express Generator to use Pug instead of Jade

Tags: javascript, pug, express-generator

I installed Express Generator for Node.js but when I created an example app, I noticed that Jade is deprecated to Pug. I installed Pug, but I still need to tell express generator to use it each time. I've been reading about the subject and it's telling developers to just change the file names manually, but is there a way for this to work out of the box? How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Express defaults to Jade but if you wish to pug as a template engine instead of using Jade.

You must type

**express --view=pug myapp**

This will create a new application called "myapp" using pug by default.

For a more in dept explanation type 
**express -h**
this will show you the available commands, one of the commands is **-v**

*--view  add view  support*

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue come when npx express-generator is used alone (for those who have node versions above Node.js 8.2.0).

for node versions 8.2.0 or above,

- Navigate to the directory where you want to create the app

  npx express-generator --view=pug myapp

  This will create a myapp folder in the directory with required .pug
  files instead of .jade files
- for earlier node versions you can find the required steps here [express
  application generator documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

Answer (score 0):

## I made two mistakes trying to follow the above docs. It's because I'm still getting used to installing packages locally and globally.

### 2 Mistakes:

- I. **npx express-generator**
  This installed it locally, making express unavailable in the command line terminal.
  When I installed it globally, I had access.
- II.  starting in a folder on Atom, an IDE. Express-generator creates a folder for you, so you start in the terminal outside of a folder, such as your desktop.

### 9 Steps to solution:

- 1. Use the terminal in your desktop directory, not an IDE.
- 2. Do not create a folder or any file.
- 3. Install express-generator globally, not locally.
- **sudo npm express-generator**
- 4. Verify you have access by: express -h
- 5. Type: express --view=pug my app
- 6. Change directories to myapp folder on desktop
- 7. npm install
- 8. DEBUG=myapp:* npm start
- 9. open your browser to http://127.0.0.1:3000/

Answer (score 0):

npx express-generator --view=pug install.

this should do the trick